# Convert date column to unix date column of a dataframe

Tags: r

Using this it gives the date time format to the specific column

```
 df[,":="(date = as.numeric(as.POSIXct(date , "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))]
```

How is it possible to convert a date column to a epoch/unix date column like this it can be for one value

```
as.numeric(as.POSIXct("2013-09-16 2:13:46 EST"))
```

Comment: Use `tz = "GMT", origin="1970-01-01"`. If your timezone is different, add/subtract the appropriate number of seconds to the result above. Or adjust the number of hours to the date/time before converting to numeric: `as.integer(as.POSIXct("2013-09-16 7:13:46", tz = "GMT"))`. Argument `origin` is optional, since R's default is `"1970-01-01"`.

Comment: @RuiBarradas-ReinstateMonic how can I make it for the whole column  df[,":="(date = as.numeric(as.POSIXct(date , "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))] ?

Comment: `df[, date := as.numeric(as.POSIXct(date , "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))]`. Your date already is in the default format, just `df[, date := as.numeric(as.POSIXct(date))]` will do the same and is simpler.